# How to build a game tree in a web app

Tags: javascript, html, tree, activex

OK - I've searched all over and can't find anything that really answers this:

I'm building a game which runs in the browser with HTML and Javascript.

The game is a football/soccer game which unfolds through a series of user choices - e.g.

"opponent slides in for a tackle" do you:

a) dodge left
b) stop running
c) pass the ball

The game continues to unfold in this manner - divs are shown/hidden depending on buttons clicked.

But this game is actually quite comprehensive - which means that the probability tree underpinning it is now very large (like 20 layers deep). I'm currently representing it in Excel - but then have to basically manually recreate it in HTML. This is massively unwieldy.

Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to make changes in Excel, and have them immediately take effect on the page - but the only way I can see that working is using the ActiveX object which comes with a whole host of issues I don't want to touch.

Should I resign myself to creating huge javascript arrays?

Comment: I don't know if I quite got your idea for the probability tree structure, but have you considered JSON? It's easier to represent hierarchical data (ie, trees) in this format. If you really have to stick with Excel, I would then suggest some form of intermediate CSV instead, for at least you wouldn't have to depend on ActiveX for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make some functions seperate from the game 'tree'.
For example if you have buttons in HTML like

| Dodge left |  | Stop Running |  | Pass the ball |

Clicking the first one would run the function `dodgeLeft();`

In the function you would calculate all sorts off outcomes which you can return as a JSON object from which you can go on to the next 'obstacle' in the game.

This way you can reuse 'actions' all over the place and the game 'tree' stays readable.

Note that you can pass variables to each function to manipulate the outcome of it and take the reusable thing to a whole new level.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks - I think you're right and that JSON is the way to go.